# Why does "a"="a" return False

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

The expression `"a"="a"` returns `False`.  What the heck is going on?

[image: Watch List]

**Edit**: Sorry, I'm working in VB.NET, not C#

**Update**: When I copy the expression into Notepad++, it shows `"?a"="a"`. Can it have something to do with encoding?

Comment: @Patashu: `=` `!=` `==`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>That expression is not legal C#.</strike>

You aren't getting an error because the FuncEval (the ability to execute code in the watch or immediate windows) uses a different parser with various issues.

These issues may eventually be fixed by replacing this parser with Roslyn.

---

### EDIT

<strike>I suspect that the VB.Net parser used by FuncEval doesn't intern strings.</strike>

If you run this expression outside of FuncEval (eg, LINQPad), it returns true.

---

### Second EDIT

You have an unprintable character in the first string.

Notepad++ shows it as a `?` because your text file is using an encoding that doesn't support the character.
To find out what it actually is, paste it into [this site](http://codepoints.net/).

Comment: Btw, I'd like to add that if in Notepad++ you go to Encoding -> encode in basically anything that's not ANSI, and are using a font that has unicode glyphs in it, it will usually show what it is.